# Potential leak of an object in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, xml-parsing

In my application in xml parsing method found character delegate method i use the fallowing code

```
NSString *Str =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:foundString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] ;

if ([weekNames containsObject:elementName]) {
  //  if (!settings) {
    //    NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"no",@"بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم",@"surah",nil];

      //  [weekDict insertObject:dict1 atIndex:0];             
    //}
    [array1 addObject:weekDict];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"DUA"]) {
    [weekDict addObject:duaDict];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    [duaDict setObject:Str forKey:@"no"];   
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SURAH"]) {
    [duaDict setObject:Str forKey:@"surah"];    
}
foundString=nil;**
```

If i use this code in analyze application i got potent6ial memory leak.
If i autorelease the **Str**  it will give too many times releasing .
Why it happens like that. Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In which object do you get memory leak ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
NSString *Str =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:foundString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

really should be:

```
NSString *Str =  [foundString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

What you are doing now is creating (alloc/init) a new NSString and then immediately leaking it, because you never actually save the pointer. And it turns out you never really needed that NSString to begin with.